# Scalability of simple algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, scalability, lda

I wish to test the scalability of two implementations of an algorithm (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) in Python - **gensim** and **lda** . Most of the google search results talk about scalability of websites and web-based applications.

How do I test the scalability of a simple algorithm (Not an entire system)? What are the best practices to kept in mind ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at following python code,

```
import datetime;

s=0
VALUES = [1,10,100,1000,2000,8000]

for VALUE in VALUES:
    timebefore =  datetime.datetime.now()
    #Algorithm starts
    for i in range(VALUE):
        for j in range(VALUE):
            s+=i*j

    #Algorithm ends
    timeafter = datetime.datetime.now()    
    print('time taken for parameter:'+str(VALUE)+" is " + str(timeafter - timebefore))
```

output of above program is

```
time taken for parameter:1 is 0:00:00
time taken for parameter:10 is 0:00:00
time taken for parameter:100 is 0:00:00
time taken for parameter:1000 is 0:00:00.327280
time taken for parameter:2000 is 0:00:01.285746
time taken for parameter:8000 is 0:00:21.250825
```

When n is changed from 1000 to 2000(by factor 2) time taken is increased roughly 4 times (1.285746/0.327280)

When n is changed from 2000 to 8000(by factor 4) time taken is increased roughly 16 times (21.250825/1.285746)

so for n change in input parameter, time taken changes by n^2,  hence complexity of algorithm can be deduced to be O(n^2)

In your case, replace algorithm with your own and run for different parameters to see the time complexity.

Comment: So, in case of Latent Dirichlet Allocation, I need to write scripts to test the two algorithms on different corpora alongwith varying the parameters. But what do I measure - just the time, or accuracy or something else ?

Comment: try varying the no. of documents fed to each algorithm and see how the code scales. I don't think accuracy has anything to do it scalability. Its just matter of time and space

Answer (score 0):

The scalability of an algorithm is determined by its time complexity, for a simple algorithm it's simply a matter of counting the maximum number of operations. A loop iterating over n elements has the time complexity O(n), meaning it will scale like any linear function, and so on. A loop with a nested loop would be O(n^2).

For a more in-depth explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity